# Do duplicated descriptor files get closed after closing the original file descriptor?

Tags: c, file-descriptor, dup2

When duplicating a file descriptor fd calling dup, and closing the original file descriptors.

Do all the duplicated file descriptors get closed also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the duplicates won't be closed. Otherwise the main use-case (duplicating into `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDIN_FILENO`) would be pretty useless.

Comment: The man page of dup does not say anything about closing, can you refer me please to the source of the information? Thank you

Comment: Well, obviously, since `dup` doesn't do any closing... You'll want to refer to some other POSIX manual page for that, perhaps one about program execution. Speaking of which, I'm pretty sure there's *one* (possibly more) case where both file descriptors will be closed: At program termination.

Comment: @Bionix1441 If you make a copy or some paper, then shred the original you still have the copy, right? It's basically the same thing here. Once you have created the copy (with `dup` or similar) then there is no link between the original and duplicated descriptor. You should probably read about *reference counting* as well, as the actual "file" being duplicated will get its reference counter incremented by one by the duplication, and the "file" will not be truly closed until the reference count is zero.

Comment: @Bionix1441 You want the source of information that something doesn't happen? It's easy. Read all the documentation in the world. No documentation says that it happens, so we can conclude that it doesn't happen. (or someone forgot to document it)

Comment: @Bionix1441 As for source, why not take some time to look at some *actual* source? There are many POSIX compatible operating systems where the source is available, and a few which are well documented in books as well. And as I said, the main use-case would not work if `close` closed the duplicates.

Comment: On a serious note, there's a difference between file descriptor and file description in POSIX. Close closes the file descriptor and file description is closed when the last reference to it is closed. It's a complicated topic and rarely important to dig into, just trust us, close doesn't close dup:ed file decsriptors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _"..Once you have created the copy (with dup or similar) then there is no link between the original and duplicated descriptor"_ **except** the fact they they point to the same open file description and share file offset and file status flags.